# Obter dados específicos de login através do facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-identity, oauth2

Estou buscando implementar *autenticação* através do `facebook`. Onde quero obter mais dados **publicos**. Já tenho o autenticação padrão configurada. Mas preciso de algo mais, porque ela me traz apenas o Email.

Estou tirando como base algumas respostas no [So-En](http://http:/StackOverflow.com) como está:

[Pergunta com Respostas do So-En](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942196/how-to-access-facebook-private-information-by-using-asp-net-identity-owin/18946026#18946026)

[Outro Artigo](http://www.theroks.com/social-login-owin-authentication-mvc5/)

Porém não consegui configurar em minha aplicação. Minha Classe Startup.Auth.cs atualmente é:

```
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            });
              app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);            
app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));             

app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
               appId: "MeuAppID",
               appSecret: "MeuAppSecret");

            // O que devo setar no FacebookAppId
            // Já Coloquei o Id da app do facebook mas não funcionou

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FacebookAppId")))
            {
                var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(""),
                    AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(""),
                    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
                            foreach (var x in context.User)
                            {
                                var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", x.Key);
                                string claimValue = x.Value.ToString();
                                if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));

                            }
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                };             
                app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
            }
        }

        const string XmlSchemaString = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A API do Facebook passou por diversas mudanças com o tempo, o que tornou a maioria destes métodos defasados.

O que você pode fazer é o seguinte:

Em seu `Startup.Auth.cs`, adicione o seguinte código:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "*",
            AppSecret = "*",
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Com isso você retornará o `FacebookAccessToken` do usuário.

O próximo passo é instalar o [Facebook SDK for .NET](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk). Com isso você poderá fazer buscas na API do Facebook sempre que for necessário.

Para utilizar, primeiro instale o pacote via NuGet com o seguinte comando:

> Install-Package Facebook

Feito isso, basta fazer a seguinte alteração em seu controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (loginInfo == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
// Verifica se o login foi via Facebook
if (loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider == "Facebook")
{
    var identity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var access_token = identity.FindFirstValue("FacebookAccessToken");
    var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);
    dynamic informacoesFacebook = fb.Get("/me?fields=id,cover,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,gender,locale,picture,email"); 

    var id = informacoesFacebook[0];
    var cover = informacoesFacebook[1];
    var name = informacoesFacebook[2];
    var first_name = informacoesFacebook[3];
    var last_name = informacoesFacebook[4];
    var age_range = informacoesFacebook[5];
    var link = informacoesFacebook[6];
    var gender = informacoesFacebook[7];
    var locale = informacoesFacebook[8];
    var picture = informacoesFacebook[9];
    var email = informacoesFacebook[10];

    loginInfo.Email = email;
}
```

Note que nesta linha que você adiciona os campos que deseja retornar:

```
dynamic informacoesFacebook = fb.Get("/me?fields=id,cover,name,first_name,last_name,
           age_range,link,gender,locale,picture,email");
```

Os campos que você pode utilizar, você pode buscar no [Explorador da Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). Nesta tela você poderá ver todos os campos que poderá receber do Facebook.

Comment: fazendo esta implementação, tive este erro: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193491/61561 está relacionado, ou fiz algo errado ?

Comment: Esse erro não  ocorre para buscar os dados, e sim na parte do Login que é feito pelo Identity. [Em minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193558/20615) eu mostro onde adicionar a URl de retorno, e você deve adicionar o `localhost:PORTA/Account/ExternalLoginCallback` nela, caso esteja utilizando o localhost. Caso já esteja online, adicione a URI do site em questão.