# Erro login facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, facebook, oauth2, oauth

Quando tento logar pelo `facebook` através da minha aplicação, dá o erro:

> URL bloqueada: O redirecionamento falhou porque o URl usado não está
>   na lista de liberação nas configurações de OAuth do cliente do
>   aplicativo. Verifique se o login de OAuth do cliente e da Web está
>   ativado e adicione todos os domínios do seu aplicativo como URls
>   válidos de redirecionamento de OAuth.

Pesquisei um pouco, e fala que habilitando o *Client OAuth Login* no Facebook developers, era pra funcionar o login.  Porem, fiz este procedimento e o erro ainda persiste.

Como faço pra resolver isso ?

Answer (score 7):

Esse erro ocorre porque a URL de retorno não está cadastrada no Facebook.

Para isso, você deve acessar o seu aplicativo e adicionar a URL de retorno. Segue um breve tutorial de como fazer esse procedimento:

1: Acesse a página de seu aplicativo, por exemplo:

> https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APPID_AQUI/dashboard/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2: Adicione o produto **Login do Facebook**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3: Em **URIs de redirecionamento do OAuth válidos**, adicione a URl de retorno da sua aplicação, ou seja, a URI em que o Facebook deverá chamar ao usuário realizar o login.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Caso você tenha uma URI que não seja válida, você deverá criar um aplicativo de testes e substituir a APPID e APPKEY de sua aplicação para a do aplicativo de testes.

Comment: Muito obrigado, essa resposta me salvou haha!

Answer (score 0):

> URL bloqueada: O redirecionamento falhou porque o URl usado não está
> na lista de liberação nas configurações de OAuth do cliente do
> aplicativo. Verifique se o login de OAuth do cliente e da Web está
> ativado e adicione todos os domínios do seu aplicativo como URls
> válidos de redirecionamento de OAuth.