# Como fazer login sem utilizar o padrão do Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, api, facebook, asp.net-identity

Uma atualização na `Api` do `Facebook` fez a forma de login padrão do `Identity` parar de funcionar. A forma que estou fazendo que deixou de funcionar está assim:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
   app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
   app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
      Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
      {
          OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, Usuario,Guid>(
          validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
          regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
          getUserIdCallback: (ci) => new Guid(ci.GetUserId()))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);          app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "*",
            AppSecret = "*",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback"),
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Quero saber, uma forma que não use a implementação padrão do `identity`, para logar em aplicações `ASP.NET MVC`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Irei responder com a premissa que você já possui o APP do facebook configurada corretamente, inclusive com o URIs de retorno válidas.

Primeiro, vamos analisar a API do Facebook (as demais como a Google segue a mesma premissa):

#### Como funciona?

- 1: O cliente solicita o acesso e permissões via SDK e Diálogo de Login;
- 2: Usuário realiza a autenticação e aprova as permissões solicitadas;
- 3: O Facebook retorna o Access token para o cliente.

Veja o [fluxo elaborado pelo Facebook na imagem abaixo:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### O que isso quer dizer em código?

Para solicitar o acesso, o Facebook diz que você precisa fazer [a seguinte solicitação:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?
      client_id={app-id}
      &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

Um exemplo de código seria este:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"
            href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APPID&response_type=code&scope=email&redirect_uri=http://localhost:51133/Conta/Facebook">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Entrar com Facebook
        </a>
```

> **client_id**. O número de identificação do seu aplicativo, encontrado no painel do aplicativo.
>
> **redirect_uri**. A URL para a qual você deseja para redirecionar a pessoa que está fazendo login. Essa URL captura a resposta da caixa de diálogo Login. Se você estiver utilizando-o em uma WebView em um aplicativo de desktop, ele deve ser definido como https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html. Para confirmar se a URL está definida para o seu aplicativo, acesse o Painel de Aplicativos, clique em Login no Facebook no menu à direita e verifique os URIs de redirecionamento do OAuth válidos na seção Configurações de OAuth do cliente.

Você fazendo isso, já irá para a página onde o usuário realiza o login no Facebook e aceita as permissões do aplicativo. Após essa aceitação, o facebook retornará o **code** para solicitar a autorização do usuário.

> **code**. Os dados de resposta são incluídos como parâmetros da URL e contêm parâmetros de code (uma cadeia de caracteres criptografada exclusiva para cada solicitação de login). Esse é o comportamento padrão se esse parâmetro não foi especificado. Ele é o mais útil quando seu servidor estiver lidando com o token.

#### Onde estamos?

Até o momento você já pediu o acesso ao usuário, ele já logou e o Facebook te retornou o código exclusivo daquele login.

Mas e agora, o que eu faço com esse código?

O próximo passa é conseguir o [access_token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) do usuário.

#### Como conseguir o Access Token?

Para conseguir o `Acess Token` você deve fazer uma requisição `POST` para o seguinte URI:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token

Como nós estamos trabalhando com [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), irei demonstrar como fazer a solicitação utilizando o [pacote do Facebook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/7.0.10-beta):

```
    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();
    dynamic result = client.Get("oauth/access_token", new
    {
        client_id = "{app-id}",
        redirect_uri = "{redirect-uri}",
        client_secret = "{app-secret}",
        code = "{code-parameter}"
    });
```

O retorno será um `JSON` parecido com isso:

```
{  
   "access_token":"access_code_aqui",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":5181174
}
```

Com isso você já pode realizar a busca dos dados do usuário, conforme expliquei [nesta resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179586/20615) Mas, relembrando, basta fazer uma solicitação dos dados que deseja obter.

```
 var fb = new FacebookClient(result.access_token);
 dynamic informacoesFacebook = fb.Get("/me?fields=id,cover,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,gender,locale,picture,email");
```

Feito isso, você já tem o e-mail e os dados do usuário. Agora basta verificar se ele já possui cadastro ou não. Você pode utilizar qualquer dado para isso, desde o e-mail ao id do facebook, então deixarei com você esse critério.

Caso o usuário possua cadastro, você apenas fará a autenticação do mesmo, caso não possua, você realiza o cadastro e após isso, realiza a autenticação. Um exemplo seria:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(result.access_token);
dynamic informacoesFacebook = fb.Get("/me?fields=id,cover,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,gender,locale,picture,email");

string email = informacoesFacebook[10];

var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);

if (user == null)
{
    //Cadastra o usuário aqui
}
else
{
    //Realiza o login aqui
}
```

> Você não precisa utilizar o Pacote do Facebook, mas teria que fazer a requisição manualmente o Facebook.

Comment: @RenanCarlos O parâmetro `code` que o Facebook lhe retorna

Comment: @RenanCarlos Neste exemplo, ele irá retornar o code aqui: `http://localhost:51133/Conta/Facebook`

Comment: @RenanCarlos O code o facebook irá retornar para o seu Controller. Olhe o Login/Facebook que está em seu controller que ele tem um parâmetro code, tipo isso: `Public ActionResult Facebook(string code)`

Comment: realmente o code chega como null pra mim.