# Inserir usuário via Identity ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `ASP.NET` onde estou utilizando `Identity`.

Tenho algumas funções iniciais proveniente de uma *API externa* que são chamadas quando estou validando o *Token* desta *API* via `controller`.

O Fato é que preciso dentro do meu `controller`, verificar se o usuário já esta cadastrado em meu sistema e caso não esteja, preciso realizar o cadastro do mesmo, tudo isso dentro deste controller, para que eu possa redirecionar o usuário para determinados locais.

Segue trecho do meu codigo

```
        Rootobject DadosUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Rootobject>(RetornoUser);

        var IDUsuario = DadosUser.id;
        var UsuarioLogin = DadosUser.nickname;
        var UsuarioPrimeiroNome = DadosUser.first_name;
        var UsuarioSegundoNome = DadosUser.last_name;
        var UsuarioEmail = DadosUser.email;



        ViewBag.UsuarioLogin = UsuarioLogin;
        ViewBag.NomeCompleto = UsuarioPrimeiroNome + " " + UsuarioSegundoNome;


        //INSERINDO NOVO USUARIO


      // Aqui preciso verificar se o usuario recebido ja existe no cadastro, e caso não, preciso cadastra-lo
```

Comment: O `Identity` já faz isso pra você. Dentro de `AccountController` tem a _ 
 _Action_ `ExternalLoginCallback`. Você pode trabalhar com ela.

Comment: Não estou sabendo como chamar a dentro deste meu controler

Comment: @ThiagoP Você quer validar como? Nome? Id? Email? Todos?

Comment: @ThiagoP Mais ou menos assim [Login sem usar o padrão identity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193787/como-fazer-login-sem-utilizar-o-padr%C3%A3o-do-identity?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @LINQ vou usar o campo de email que recebi da API para ser o usuario